# How do i create a button in another window by pressing a button kivy/kivymd/python

Tags: python, button, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to create a button by pressing a button, but I cant find any information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach in kivy or kivyMD.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


KV = '''

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    
    Screen:
        id: screenID
        
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Create Button"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            on_release: app.createButton()
'''

class Example(MDApp):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty() # IMPORTANT!

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def build(self):
        return self.screen

    def createButton(self):
        print("button created")
        self.btn = MDRaisedButton(text= "New Button", pos_hint= {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .7})
        self.root.ids.screenID.add_widget(self.btn)


Example().run()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Create new hotlink",
                            command=self.create_window)
        self.button.pack(side="top")

    def create_window(self):
        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("All the best to hackathon")
        fields = 'Hotlink Name', 'URL'

        def fetch(entries):
            for entry in entries:
                field = entry[0]
                text = entry[1].get()
                print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))

        def makeform(root, fields):
            entries = []
            for field in fields:
                row = Frame(root)
                lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
                ent = Entry(row)
                row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
                lab.pack(side=LEFT)
                ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
                entries.append((field, ent))
            return entries

        def button2():
            newButton = tk.Button(root, text=fields[0])
            newButton.pack(side=RIGHT)

            ents = makeform(t, fields)
            t.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
            b2 = Button(t, text='Save', command=button2)
            b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```